# How to set up an old PC to run a gaming server and have people connect it?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, games, minecraft

For starters, I am extremely new to the ubuntu community and even with UNIX itself...

I have managed to wipe an old gaming computer, stack it with some ram, install ubuntu desktop 14.04, and from following some guides get a minecraft server running locally.

Now when I say locally, I can turn on the 'server', log onto the said server using putty and launch the minecraft platform through putty and then run around giving commands etc. through my PC.  This is great and all, but I have absolutely no idea how a friend outside of my LAN would be able to connect to the server.

I have a vague idea of how the minecraft platform and how remote connection works in the first place.  Does anyone know of a way to set up the server the way that I want in general i.e. put a game on the server, and have people connect to it remotely and locally?  Or at least could point me in the direction of what to even search for in google to do some self learnage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Connecting inside your LAN:

1. Just type in the local IP, the one output from "ifconfig" or "ip address".

To have people outside your LAN connect:

1. Forward a port to your game server's local IP address. In order to not have to adjust the forwarding all the time, you'll probably want to assign your game server a static IP address from your router.
2. Anyone outside your network can then connect by using your external IP* and that port that you forwarded to your game server.

*Suggestion: Instead of having to tell everyone your new external IP every time it changes, you can use an online service to give it a name that updates automatically (like game.server.org, for example, but it will always resolve to your external IP). This is called dynamic DNS, you can search that if you're interested.

Comment: Just to show how nub I am with this, I thought that local and remote users would use the same address. Definitely clears up that issue for me! And I'll have to look into that dynamic DNS. Thanks!